# Why "hung it from a tree" and not "hung it on a tree"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Why in the given context is it "*from* a tree" but not "*on* a tree"?

Please explain with a rule or something. What's the rule [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/from) can correspond?

> Boo carried the ribbon into the garden and carefully hung it **from** a tree

[image: hung from a tree]

Comment: There is no rule that I know of. "Hang something on something" and "hang something from something" mean much the same thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'd say size and 'swinging potential' matter. We hung the bauble on the tree. They hung the swing from the tree.

Comment: Both “hung on a tree and from a tree” are commonly used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hung+from+a+tree%2C+hung+on+a+tree&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chung%20from%20a%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chung%20on%20a%20tree%3B%2Cc0

Comment: -1 Just tell us how you would hang something *on* a tree.

Comment: @kris The same way you'd hang a hat _on_ a hook. In other words you would place it so that the end of a branch was inside the object and only part of the object was suspended below the branch. If I hung a pair of shoes _from_ a tree by their laces the shoes would be swinging free and only the laces (which aren't part of the shoes) would be touching the tree.

Comment: One would hang a string of lights **on a tree** (if they went around or through), or **from a tree** (if they simply hung down (away **from** ) the tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an idiomatic usage: ***[hang someone or something from something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hang+from) :***

> to suspend someone or something from something.
>
> - *The captain wanted to hang him from the highest yardarm as punishment. I hung a colorful decoration from the windowsill.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)